# how to display the image title tooltip ontouch in mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am making a responsive website. in mobile size, I want to display title tooltip on the image where I touch. please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: where is your code, can you provide a working example?

Answer (score 0):

I see this answer. You can consult it

This is link [link post](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/98628/how-can-i-display-tool-tips-on-a-touchscreen-or-is-there-a-better-way).

Comment: I want to display title tooltip on the image when the mobile user click on the image.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JavaScript click function for this.

html

```
<span class="tooltip" title="This is the tooltip">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/02/07/16/47/kingfisher-2046453_960_720.jpg" width="100" height="100">
</span>
```

css

```
.tooltip {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
 }

.tooltip .title-info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    background: purple;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 4px;
    left: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

JavaScript

```
$(".tooltip").click(function () {
    var $title = $(this).find(".title-info");
    if (!$title.length) {
        $(this).append('<span class="title-info">' + $(this).attr("title") + '</span>');
    } else {
        $title.remove();
    }
});
```